# ASTParser: Find Declaring Node after resolve Bindings

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I crate an AST with Bindings enabled and when I resolve bindings later I get a valid ITypeBinding.
However when I want to get the declaring Node of the binding, it always returns null (unless the ITypeBinding was declared in the sourceFile).

Here is my Code for the AST generation:

```java
public void parseFunction(IFile sourceFile) {
        ICompilationUnit element = JavaCore.createCompilationUnitFrom(sourceFile);
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS14);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
        parser.setSource(element);

        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

            public boolean visit(FieldDeclaration variable) {
                ITypeBinding binding = variable.getType().resolveBinding();
                //binding is not null here
                ASTNode declartionNode = cu.findDeclaringNode(binding);
                //declartionNode is null here
                return false;
            }

        });
        return;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So your `ITypeBinding` is a `IMethodBinding`, right? With `ASTNode declartionNode = compilationUnit.findDeclaringNode(binding);` you will get the `MethodDeclaration` where `parameters()` returns a list of the parameters and for a parameter you can get the name with `getName()`.

Comment: This does however only work, if the Declaring Node is in the AST, Right? 
I have only the AST of one Class, but need the constructors of all Types used in that class. 
I know exactly what I need to do, once I have an AstNode, it‘s just that I haven’t managed to get there yet.

Comment: AFAIK `findDeclaringNode(binding)` might also return an AST node of the system library or of a dependency when creating the compilation unit with a parser with `parser.setResolveBindings(true)`. Please [show your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I see, `parser.setEnvironment(classpath, sources, encodings, true);` is missing. Otherwise, a binding to a declaration not in the parsed code, but somewhere on the classpath cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
parser.setEnvironment(classpath, sources, encodings, true);
```

is missing.

Otherwise, a binding to a declaration not in the parsed code, but somewhere on the classpath cannot be resolved.

See [ASTParser::setEnvironment](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html#setEnvironment(java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D,boolean))

Comment: This is only needed when no IJavaProject is available.
But parser.setSource(ICompilationUnit) automatically sets the project (and compileroptions) based on the given compilation unit

The binding is resolved, that's not the problem, but I can't find the declaring node

Comment: I even tried it with the environment settings, but I still get no ASTNode back, even though the binding is valid.

Comment: Does it work when the declaration is in the same file or in a different source file?

Comment: I always get the binding, but the ASTNode is Null, except when the Declaration is in the same File.

Comment: Like here: the String would return null, but T would return the correct ASTNode
 
`public class T {
    String s
    T t;
}`

Comment: The Javadoc tells _"Use `findDeclaringNode(binding.getKey())` when the binding comes from a different AST."_ Does this solve it for you?

Comment: Doesn't change anything, sadly

Comment: In [this code snippet (see `getASTNodeForBinding(...)`)](https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core/src/org/eclipse/jdt/apt/core/internal/env/BaseProcessorEnv.java.shtml) it looks like you first have to create the compile unit that contains the declaration.

Comment: I did try that, however the unit is still null, even though the member isn’t:

Comment: if( member != null ){
    unit = member.getCompilationUnit();
   }