# Given a ASTNode how to find the method body using Eclipse JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have an ASTNode and I need to find out the method name this ASTNode is defined on. If it defined in the class itself, then I need find out the class name.

As an example, ASTNode is pointing to "\R" and I need to find out the method it is defnied on i.e. `emitAndIndent(String s)`. Example below:

```
/** 
 * Emits  {@code s} with indentation as required. It's important that all code that writes to{@link #out} does it through here, since we emit indentation lazily in order to avoidunnecessary trailing whitespace.
 */
CodeWriter emitAndIndent(String s) throws IOException {
  boolean first=true;
  for (  String line : s.split("\\R",-1)) {
    if (!first) {
      if ((javadoc || comment) && trailingNewline) {
        emitIndentation();
        out.append(javadoc ? " *" : "//");
      }
      out.append("\n");
      trailingNewline=true;
      if (statementLine != -1) {
        if (statementLine == 0) {
          indent(2);
        }
        statementLine++;
      }
    }
    first=false;
    if (line.isEmpty())     continue;
    if (trailingNewline) {
      emitIndentation();
      if (javadoc) {
        out.append(" * ");
      }
 else       if (comment) {
        out.append("// ");
      }
    }
    out.append(line);
    trailingNewline=false;
  }
  return this;
}
```

Currently, I am recursively checking like newASTNode.parent and then newASTNode.parent.parent, so on and so forth.

Is the correct way?

Comment: I do not understand your code and how it is related to your question since it does not contains `ASTNode`. You might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/65254336/6505250

Comment: @howlger I gave a code example where I have to extract body of `emitAndIndent`.